# RcppArmadillo undefined symbol: dpotrf_ in Travis build

Tags: travis-ci, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I have looked at many other posts related to this issue and have tried each solution. None have worked in my case, including copying over the makevars from `Rcpp`. Anyhow, when building on Travis I get the following error

`undefined symbol: dpotrf_’`

The interesting note is that the package installs fine on windows, macOS, and linux.

here is my repo [R package](https://github.com/donaldRwilliams/BGGM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work with D_Williams, but I figured out the problem, and others may find it useful.

A functioning `configure.ac` was present, and a Makevars.in is present. 
The problem is that the `configure` file was not yet generated. This is an autotools/autoconf setup. To resolve it, I ran `autoconf` in the package directory, which generated the `configure` file. That `configure` file is then executed when R builds the package. The `configure` file modifies the `Makevars.in` and creates `Makevars`. That `Makevars` file ultimately defines where to find libraries, includes, compilers, compiler options, etc.

If you do *not* generate the `configure` file from `configure.ac` using `autoconf`, then there is no `configure` file to be executed, and no `Makevars` to define the needed options at compile time. Therefore, the compiler is not fully configured, and it will fail.

TLDR: If you have an `configure.ac`, you *must* run `autoconf` on it, and commit that configure file to your repo. R needs to execute it to have a functioning Makevars.

Comment: Well, yes. That is how autoconf is supposed to work.  If you could, please edit the Subject: line of the question to append maybe 'under uncomplete setup'.  Armadillo, and RcppArmadillo, find LAPACK symbols reliably if the Makevars snippet we document is used.

Comment: To be clear - Yes, I know that is how autoconf is supposed to work. This is an answer for others to find in case they hit a similar error message. He came to me, I noticed that problem, and I fixed it. I imagine others may also overlook the autoconf step, so this is a brief explanation for what needs to be run, and why the error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the failure on a very standard Debian testing system (which I use for the *extensive* reverse dependency checks on Rcpp and RcppArmadillo).

After installing packages `bain` and `BFpack` (I had the rest) I attempted to build the tar.gz from your pristine just-checked-out sources.  And I get:

```
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘BGGM’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/tmp/Rinst106c6ed5251a/00LOCK-BGGM/00new/BGGM/libs/BGGM.so':
  /tmp/Rinst106c6ed5251a/00LOCK-BGGM/00new/BGGM/libs/BGGM.so: undefined symbol: dpotrf_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/tmp/Rinst106c6ed5251a/BGGM’
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
```

This appears to be a moderately complex and large enough package so please pardon me for not diving in and debugging. I would suggest you simplify with smaller mock packages to see what may be wrong.  ([`dpotrf`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dpotrf.f.html) is a fairly standard LAPACK routine so something somewhere calls it.  Maybe you call it explicitly. Maybe you did a Fortran-to-C mapping wrong. Maybe you have something wrong in how you interface with RcppArmadillo. Hard to tell...)

*Edit:* You committed compiled code and a Windows library. "Don't do that."  When Travis builds it also starts from a `git` checkout as I did.  That may be the difference.

*Edit 2:* It wasn't, but your R code mixes `.Call()` with generated entry points (ie via RcppExports.cpp and RcppExports.R). I have seen that blow up for other people.  That may be something to look into.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am starting a mock package as you suggested to see if I can find the error. One point of clarification, what should I replace `.Call()` with  ?

Comment: Look at basic Rcpp Introductions (_e.g._ our vignette) and see how Rcpp Attributes generally turns a C++ function `int doSomething(int a) {...}` with an export tag into something R can call via `doSomething()`.  We promoted that way as the better since about 2013.

Comment: Sounds good. I guess perhaps I did not follow the instruction closely enough. Anyhow, I *think* I may have found the error, based on a new mock package as you suggested. In the main package, there was a line ending error, i.e., that non-windows requires LF. I changed the `.ac` file accordingly and that error is gone and at least the mock version does not have the `dpotrf` error when building on Travis.

Comment: Note the mock version has *all* of the `c++` functions, so perhaps not an interface issue. Of course, I will still change `.Call()` as well.

Comment: I have isolated the error. Basically the package passes with just the makevars, but not the makevars.in that was added to be used with macOS (in addition to the other files, such as clean, configure.ac). Here is the mock package if you might be able to help a bit more (highly appreciated to say the least) . https://github.com/donaldRwilliams/bggmMock

Comment: "The Makevars.in [...] to be used with macOS".  Unless I misread I fear you may be under some misunderstandings concerning R package builds.  Consult Writing R Extensions and/or ask on r-package-devel.  And, again, test on simpler and simpler packages.

Comment: I have tested the simpler package. And I do not think I misunderstood (but note also I am not professing to be an expert here). My package could not be installed on macOS due to the openmp issue, so I followed some online tutorials for addressing that. One part of that was changing Makervars to Makevars.in, in addition to some other changes. Further, I appreciate all you do and your time, but referring me to the "writing R extensions" is not all that helpful. I am trying to develop a software for others to use (like you) and am just a bit stuck right now. that is all.

Comment: I provide you with tools that works for hundreds of other users (700+ RcppArmadillo-using packages on CRAN alone). You created a large and fairly complex package.  I am truly sorry, but I cannot one-off debug it for you.  However I can (and will) point out that many other examples work, including with OpenMP, and including macOS.  They provide existence proofs, and maybe you can find a missing link. Our documentation also makes it clear we prefer the mailing list for questions over these four line comment boxen here.

Comment: That is fine. And I understand. Was hoping that the answer was readily available. I will do some digging.