# Install package() - Non Zero Exit Status (Non CRAN package)

Tags: r, boost, path, install.packages

I'm have a problem installing a package. This package does not seem to want to load. I've tried to install many times, checked working directory and install path. Any recommendations for getting this to work? Or information I'm not understanding about the error messages. Full code below:

```
install.packages("/programs/apps/BoostMLRpackage/BoostMLR_2.0.1.tar.gz",repos = NULL, dependencies = TRUE)
```

CONSOLE:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/kramerb2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘BoostMLR’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c BoostMLR.cpp -o BoostMLR.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o BoostMLR.so BoostMLR.o RcppExports.o -L/opt/R-4.2.2/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/kramerb2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-BoostMLR/00new/BoostMLR/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘BoostMLR’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/kramerb2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-BoostMLR/00new/BoostMLR/libs/BoostMLR.so':
  /home/kramerb2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-BoostMLR/00new/BoostMLR/libs/BoostMLR.so: undefined symbol: dpotrf_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/kramerb2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/BoostMLR’
* restoring previous ‘/home/kramerb2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/BoostMLR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/programs/apps/BoostMLRpackage/BoostMLR_2.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: The relevant bit seems to be "undefined symbol: dpotrf_", so oyu could search in that. Anything useful at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765652/rcpparmadillo-undefined-symbol-dpotrf-in-travis-build. PS Is it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BoostMLR/index.html you are installing or something different? Can you share?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/flame/libflame/issues/20) tangentially related R issue also seems to point to configure file.

Comment: This is an updated version not yet available on the CRAN. In reading the referenced post it seems that I need to "run autoconf in the package directory, [to] generate the configure file." How does one do this? I do not see a function `autoconf` within R?

Comment: First check that your package has an `configure.ac` or else this is all moot -- is there one? [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) is not an R package. Your linux distro likely has `autoconf` pre-installed but if not use `apt`, or whichever relevant command, to install. Then run `autoconf` in the same directory as your configure.ac file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, as I'm unsure about how to check this. To help facilitate my education/troubleshooting i've also uploaded the package materials I have access to within my github (https://github.com/bptkramer/BoostMLR). Any further insight is appreciated. This is all I have access to.

Comment: You have uploaded a zip file ... is it the windows binary / previous build attempt? ... but no source files. Can you upload the contents of `BoostMLR_2.0.1.tar.gz`?

Comment: I've uploaded the contents to the github repository (https://github.com/bptkramer/BoostMLR)

Comment: Thanks. Your upload is a bit goosed. All the directory structure that an R package has has been destroyed ...  the R files, src files, man pages and others are all mingled So I would be unable to attempt to install in R without manually arranging. That said, there is not a configure.ac script so my previous comments are perhaps not relevant.

Comment: what versions of Rcpp and RcppArmadillo do you have?

Comment: Rcpp (1.0.10) and RcppArmadillo (0.11.4.2.1)

Comment: This error was corrected by using a different install server.